# Symfony - curl error 60: certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, composer-php, git-bash

I'm trying to create a webapp project with the command `symfony new webProject --version="6.2.*" –webapp` and this is the result I get:

```
* Creating a new Symfony 6.2.* project with Composer
(running C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\dev\webProject 6.2.* --no-interaction)

exit status 1

Creating a "symfony/skeleton" project at "./webProject"
Installing symfony/skeleton (v6.2.99)
  - Installing symfony/skeleton (v6.2.99): Extracting archive
Created project in C:\Uraf\dev\webProject
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking symfony/flex (v2.3.3)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v2.3.3): Extracting archive
Generating autoload files
1 package you are using is looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

In CurlDownloader.php line 365: curl error 60 while downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json: SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain

  unable to run C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\Uraf\dev\webProject 6.2.* --no-interaction
```

I had been using symfonyCLI without problems for several months already on my PC until the day when I tried to add "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle" and "symfony/flex" in my last 6.3 project. And that's where it all started. I always get this error: `curl error 60: certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain.`

I use gitbash (windows).
Help please.

EDIT

- gitbash cURL version : 8.1.2 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/8.1.2 Schannel zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh2/1.11.0 Release-Date: 2023-05-30
- I encounter this error since I installed "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle" and "symfony/flex" on a new Symfony 6.3 project
- And anyway, every time I use SymfonyCLI and symfony/Flex is requested, everything stops. My pc can no longer download FLEX recipes because of this self-signed certificate problem.

Comment: Which version of cUrl are you using? Are you also using WAMP or XAMPP server?

Comment: While trying to correct the error encountered, I discover that I have a cURL on my windows.
I have a Xamp server with its cUrl too. And finally gitbash also has its cURL. I tend to believe that it's the gitbash cURL that is used by synfonyCLI since that's where I run all my synfonyCLI commands.
Here is the output of the `curl -V` command on gitbash :                                             ```$ curl -V
curl 8.1.2 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/8.1.2 Schannel zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh2/1.11.0
Release-Date: 2023-05-30
$```

Comment: It sounds pretty strange that a self signed certificate is used for raw.githubusercontent.com. Do you use any proxy server? Also, are you sure this problem is related to Symfony itself? If not, please remove that tag

Comment: No I don't have a proxy installed on my pc @NicoHaase. It's weird for me too this behavior that I encounter since when I add "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle" and "symfony/flex" on a new Symfony 6.3 project. There are a few things that got corrupted.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Nobody has a solution for me ? I admit that my problem is very strange. I will have to change pc if I want to continue doing Symfony.

Comment: Still, your problem sounds strange to me. Did you configure any certificates on your own? Then revert this. Does your internet provider inject any other certificates? What happens if you  open the URL that is part of the error message in your web browser?

Comment: Yes @NicoHaase I added a certificate with the command `symfony server:ca:install` on my 6.3 project. I deleted it when I started getting the errors but nothing happened, the problem persisted. I can access the url `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json` in my browser, even with the command `curl -i -v https://raw .githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json`